# Gmail API: Uploading inline attachments to draft message

Tags: gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API directly. I was able to send a message with attached and inline attachments using this URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send

In the documentation, it is said that I should use the upload URI but I was not able to construct proper request for it.

Anyway, now I tried the same for creating a draft message and for some reason the inline attachments are added as attached files. I'm using the same request structure as for the send:

```
From:
Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 10:22:27 +0000
Subject: [subject]
Message-Id: [internetMessageId]
Importance: low
To: [receiver]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-knCVLgE13LKcqJaIUhH/sg=="

--=-knCVLgE13LKcqJaIUhH/sg==
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=-y0HXgc0QJcTY91BQZr4YAw=="

--=-y0HXgc0QJcTY91BQZr4YAw==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-8wbiVX9FveJH/GI7+yiHtg=="

--=-8wbiVX9FveJH/GI7+yiHtg==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

 4 draaaaft
 some text here and then the image:

 some more text
--=-8wbiVX9FveJH/GI7+yiHtg==
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css" style="display:none">
<!--
p
    {margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body dir="ltr">
<div id="divtagdefaultwrapper" dir="ltr" style="font-size:12pt; color:#000000; font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
<p> 4 draaaaft</p>
<p>some text here and then the image:</p>
<p><img size="3542" tabindex="0" src="cid:1112ed9d-acf8-4144-aa40-2468a3943eb7" style="max-width:99.9%"></p>
<p>some more text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

--=-8wbiVX9FveJH/GI7+yiHtg==--

--=-y0HXgc0QJcTY91BQZr4YAw==
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=pic3.jpeg
Content-Id: <1112ed9d-acf8-4144-aa40-2468a3943eb7>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=pic3.jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

[file content in base64]

--=-y0HXgc0QJcTY91BQZr4YAw==--

--=-knCVLgE13LKcqJaIUhH/sg==
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="file attached.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file attached.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

[file content in base64]

--=-knCVLgE13LKcqJaIUhH/sg==--
```

Comment: What error did you get? You may refer with these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440521/example-of-creating-a-draft-with-an-attachment-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429324/gmail-api-unable-to-add-an-attachment-in-a-draft.

Comment: I don't get any errors. The draft message is created, but the inline attachment is added twice - once as an inline attachment and once more as an attached file. When i send the message only the attached file is shown for the recipient.