# Example of sending mail with attachment in gmail using api. How will the body request be like working example?

Tags: gmail-api

I have seen the API documentation still not getting it. Could someone give me the following :

1) The exact URL which I should use
2) The headers which I should use exactly
3) The Body Request which I should use

Could someone help me with it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me worked: adding the attachments to the raw body of the request to the endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send. This is tested with files up to 25MB.
I also couldn't figure out how to use the upload endpoint.

To add the attachment to the raw body i add a new Mime part (to the multipart/related) of type the same as the attachment mime type and you also need to add the Content-Disposition header to set if the attachment is inline or attached.

You can check here for more information on MIME messages:
https://www.qcode.co.uk/post/70

Comment: Can u post the raw body by which you tested and was working ?

Comment: You can check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440023/gmail-api-uploading-inline-attachments-to-draft-message